# How do I make my vertical navbar's text stay at the same place when it opens?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a vertical navbar on my project and I think it's almost finalized but when I click on the "hamburger" menu (three lines) the text inside the navbar move in a weird way during the transition from close to open navbar. I would like it to stay still while the navbar opens.
Also I'm using Bootstrap and I would appreciate any help but even more if it can fit any device (responsive) !

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px"; 
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

```css
 .nav div {
  height: 4px; /*4px*/
  background-color: white;
  margin : 5px 0;/*5px 0*/
  border-radius: 25px;
  transition: 0.3s;
 }

 .nav {
  width: 30px;/*30px*/
  display: block;
  margin : 1em 0 0 1em;

 }

 .one {
  width: 30px;/*30px*/
 }

 .two {
  width: 25px;/*25px*/
 }

 .three {
  width: 20px;/*20px*/
 }

 .nav:hover div{
  width: 30px;/*30px*/
 }


 .sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 0px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition : 0.1s;/*0.3s*/
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
 position: relative;
 left: 36%;
}

.dropdown-menu {
border: 0;
border-radius: 0;
}

ul {

padding: 8px 0px 8px 32px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 25px;
color: #818181;
transition: 0.3s;
padding-left: 0px;
left: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
}

.mainNav li:hover ul{
  display: block;
}

.scroll {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <title></title>
 </head>

    <body style="background-color: white;">




<!-- Code du Navbar vertical -->
<div class ="container-fluid" style="background-color: white; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;padding-bottom: 0px;padding-top:0px;overflow-y: auto;" >
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="nav" onclick="openNav()" draggable ="false">
  <div class="one" style="background-color: black;" draggable ="false"></div>
  <div class="two" style="background-color: black;" draggable ="false"></div>
  <div class="three" style="background-color: black;" draggable ="false"></div>
 </a>

  
 <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav" style="z-index: 3;">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>

  <ul class = "mainNav">
  <li><a href="#active" draggable ="false">Home</a></li>
  <div >
  <li><a href="#" draggable ="false">Catalog</a>

      <div class="scroll">
        <div class ="tops">
      <ul><a  href="#" style="font-size: 20px" draggable ="false">Tops</a>

        <li><a href="#" style="font-size: 14px" draggable ="false">Tees + Tanks</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" style="font-size: 14px" draggable ="false">Graphic Tees</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" style="font-size: 14px" draggable ="false">Shirts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" style="font-size: 14px" draggable ="false">Polos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" style="font-size: 14px" draggable ="false">Hoodies + Sweatshirts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" style="font-size: 14px" draggable ="false">Sweaters + Cardigans</a></li>
      </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="bottoms">
      <ul><a  href="#" style="font-size: 20px" draggable ="false">Bottoms</a>

        <li><a href="#" style="font-size: 14px" draggable ="false">Jeans</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" style="font-size: 14px" draggable ="false">Shorts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" style="font-size: 14px" draggable ="false">Pants</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" style="font-size: 14px" draggable ="false">Joggers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" style="font-size: 14px" draggable ="false">Overrall</a></li>


      </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="S&A">
      <ul><a  href="#" style="font-size: 20px" draggable ="false">Shoes and accessories</a>

        <li><a href="#" style="font-size: 14px" draggable ="false">Shoes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" style="font-size: 14px" draggable ="false">Sunglasses & Readers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" style="font-size: 14px" draggable ="false">Jewelry</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" style="font-size: 14px" draggable ="false">Watches</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" style="font-size: 14px" draggable ="false">Socks & Underwear</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" style="font-size: 14px" draggable ="false">Hats & Beanies</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" style="font-size: 14px" draggable ="false">Bags & Backpacks</a></li>

      </ul>
        </div>


      <ul><a  href="#" style="font-size: 20px" draggable ="false">Sales</a></ul>




      </div>
  </li>
  </div>
  <li><a href="#" draggable ="false">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" draggable ="false">Contact</a></li>
</div>
</ul>
</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you could also put your code into a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) then it'll help us see the issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change it like this:

```
    .sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 250px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: -250;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}


<script>
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.left ="0"; 
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.left ="-250";
}

</script>
```

you are changing the width while your text font is set to a static number. so while you are changing the width the html is trying to set the text of same length to a different width, and there is nothing to do with it. So instead of changing the width. just create a static "box", put it to the left so it wouldn't be seen, and bring it right after clicking on a button.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue you're having is because the width is gradually increased.

This means that as it grows, the text goes broken over 2 lines on your longer link names. See example in the image below:

[image]

There would be a few ways to fix this but I think the simplest would be to add a `min-width: 200px;` to your `.sidenav a` selector like so:

```css
.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 0px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.1s;
  min-width: 200px;
}
```

See this [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j1vserba/) for an example

Comment: Thanks this does work altough the "close" button then gets moved in the center of the navbar :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of width you need to set the left position to remove the flickering text issue.
Please refer to the below demo.

Working Demo Code

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <title></title>
</head>

<style>
  /* Code du Navbar à 3 lignes*/
  
  .nav div {
    height: 4px;
    /*4px*/
    background-color: white;
    margin: 5px 0;
    /*5px 0*/
    border-radius: 25px;
    transition: 0.3s;
  }
  
  .nav {
    width: 30px;
    /*30px*/
    display: block;
    margin: 1em 0 0 1em;
  }
  
  .one {
    width: 30px;
    /*30px*/
  }
  
  .two {
    width: 25px;
    /*25px*/
  }
  
  .three {
    width: 20px;
    /*20px*/
  }
  
  .nav:hover div {
    width: 30px;
    /*30px*/
  }
  
  .sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 250px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: -250px;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
  }
  
  .sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 0px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.1s;
    /*0.3s*/
  }
  
  .sidenav a:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
  }
  
  .sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
  }
  
  @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .sidenav {
      padding-top: 15px;
    }
    .sidenav a {
      font-size: 18px;
    }
  }
  
  .dropdown-toggle::after {
    position: relative;
    left: 36%;
  }
  
  .dropdown-menu {
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  
  ul {
    padding: 8px 0px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    transition: 0.3s;
    padding-left: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  
  .mainNav li:hover ul {
    display: block;
  }
  
  .scroll {
    overflow: auto;
  }
</style>

<body style="background-color: white;">




  <!-- Code du Navbar vertical -->
  <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: white; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;padding-bottom: 0px;padding-top:0px;overflow-y: auto;">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="nav" onclick="openNav()" draggable="false">
      <div class="one" style="background-color: black;" draggable="false"></div>
      <div class="two" style="background-color: black;" draggable="false"></div>
      <div class="three" style="background-color: black;" draggable="false"></div>
    </a>


    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav" style="z-index: 3;">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>

      <ul class="mainNav">
        <li><a href="#active" draggable="false">Home</a></li>
        <div>
          <li><a href="#" draggable="false">Catalog</a>

            <div class="scroll">
              <div class="tops">
                <ul><a href="#" style="font-size: 20px" draggable="false">Tops</a>

                  <li><a href="#" style="font-size: 14px" draggable="false">Tees + Tanks</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" style="font-size: 14px" draggable="false">Graphic Tees</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" style="font-size: 14px" draggable="false">Shirts</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" style="font-size: 14px" draggable="false">Polos</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" style="font-size: 14px" draggable="false">Hoodies + Sweatshirts</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" style="font-size: 14px" draggable="false">Sweaters + Cardigans</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>

              <div class="bottoms">
                <ul><a href="#" style="font-size: 20px" draggable="false">Bottoms</a>

                  <li><a href="#" style="font-size: 14px" draggable="false">Jeans</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" style="font-size: 14px" draggable="false">Shorts</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" style="font-size: 14px" draggable="false">Pants</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" style="font-size: 14px" draggable="false">Joggers</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" style="font-size: 14px" draggable="false">Overrall</a></li>


                </ul>
              </div>

              <div class="S&A">
                <ul><a href="#" style="font-size: 20px" draggable="false">Shoes and accessories</a>

                  <li><a href="#" style="font-size: 14px" draggable="false">Shoes</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" style="font-size: 14px" draggable="false">Sunglasses & Readers</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" style="font-size: 14px" draggable="false">Jewelry</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" style="font-size: 14px" draggable="false">Watches</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" style="font-size: 14px" draggable="false">Socks & Underwear</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" style="font-size: 14px" draggable="false">Hats & Beanies</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" style="font-size: 14px" draggable="false">Bags & Backpacks</a></li>

                </ul>
              </div>


              <ul><a href="#" style="font-size: 20px" draggable="false">Sales</a></ul>




            </div>
          </li>
        </div>
        <li><a href="#" draggable="false">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" draggable="false">Contact</a></li>
    </div>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </div>


  <script>
    function openNav() {
      document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.left = "0px";
    }

    function closeNav() {
      document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.left = "-250px";
    }
  </script>


</body>

</html>
```